# How to create a page-jump when linking a page from another page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend, hammer.js

I have a few sections on my webpage which become active as I scroll or click the specific link on the side navbar. I want to jump to a certain section when I visit this page from another page without having to scroll down again.

Here is the HTML code

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="outer-nav--return"></div>
      <div id="viewport" class="l-viewport">
        <div class="l-wrapper">
          
          <nav class="l-side-nav">
            <ul class="side-nav">
              <li class="is-active"><span>1</span></li>
              <li><span>2</span></li>
              <li><span>3</span></li>
              <li><span>4</span></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <ul class="l-main-content main-content">
            <li class="l-section section section--is-active">
            /* CONTENT 1*/
            </li>
            <li class="l-section section">
            /* CONTENT 2*/
            </li>
            <li class="l-section section">
            /* CONTENT 3*/
            </li>
            <li class="l-section section" id="contactmi">
            /* CONTENT 4*/
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
    <ul class="outer-nav">
      <li class="is-active">1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>      
   </ul>
  </div>
```

And here are the JavaScript functions I have used to navigate between these sections.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  var canScroll = true,
      scrollController = null;
  $(this).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
    if (!($('.outer-nav').hasClass('is-vis'))) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var delta = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta) ? -e.originalEvent.wheelDelta : e.originalEvent.detail * 20;
      if (delta > 50 && canScroll) {
        canScroll = false;
        clearTimeout(scrollController);
        scrollController = setTimeout(function(){
          canScroll = true;
        }, 800);
        updateHelper(1);
      }
      else if (delta < -50 && canScroll) {
        canScroll = false;
        clearTimeout(scrollController);
        scrollController = setTimeout(function(){
          canScroll = true;
        }, 800);
        updateHelper(-1);
      }

    }

  }, {passive: false});

  $('.side-nav li, .outer-nav li').click(function(){

    if (!($(this).hasClass('is-active'))) {

      var $this = $(this),
          curActive = $this.parent().find('.is-active'),
          curPos = $this.parent().children().index(curActive),
          nextPos = $this.parent().children().index($this),
          lastItem = $(this).parent().children().length - 1;
      updateNavs(nextPos);
      updateContent(curPos, nextPos, lastItem);
    }
  });
  

  $(document).keyup(function(e){
    if (!($('.outer-nav').hasClass('is-vis'))) {
      e.preventDefault();
      updateHelper(e);
    }
  }, {passive: false});

  function updateHelper(param) {
    var curActive = $('.side-nav').find('.is-active'),
        curPos = $('.side-nav').children().index(curActive),
        lastItem = $('.side-nav').children().length - 1,
        nextPos = 0;
    if (param.type === "swipeup" || param.keyCode === 40 || param > 0) {
      if (curPos !== lastItem) {
        nextPos = curPos + 1;
        updateNavs(nextPos);
        updateContent(curPos, nextPos, lastItem);
      }
      else {
        updateNavs(nextPos);
        updateContent(curPos, nextPos, lastItem);
      }
    }
    else if (param.type === "swipedown" || param.keyCode === 38 || param < 0){
      if (curPos !== 0){
        nextPos = curPos - 1;
        updateNavs(nextPos);
        updateContent(curPos, nextPos, lastItem);
      }
      else {
        nextPos = lastItem;
        updateNavs(nextPos);
        updateContent(curPos, nextPos, lastItem);
      }
    }
  }

  function updateNavs(nextPos) {
    $('.side-nav, .outer-nav').children().removeClass('is-active');
    $('.side-nav').children().eq(nextPos).addClass('is-active');
    $('.outer-nav').children().eq(nextPos).addClass('is-active');
  }

  function updateContent(curPos, nextPos, lastItem) {
    $('.main-content').children().removeClass('section--is-active');
    $('.main-content').children().eq(nextPos).addClass('section--is-active');
    $('.main-content .section').children().removeClass('section--next section--prev');

    if (curPos === lastItem && nextPos === 0 || curPos === 0 && nextPos === lastItem) {
      $('.main-content .section').children().removeClass('section--next section--prev');
    }
    else if (curPos < nextPos) {
      $('.main-content').children().eq(curPos).children().addClass('section--next');
    }
    else {
      $('.main-content').children().eq(curPos).children().addClass('section--prev');
    }

    if (nextPos !== 0 && nextPos !== lastItem) {
      $('.header--cta').addClass('is-active');
    }
    else {
      $('.header--cta').removeClass('is-active');
    }
  }
}, {passive: false});
```

Now how do I want to create a link from another page which directly goes to the content section D instead of having me to scroll down to it after reaching to this page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using simple [Anchor](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html) like:

First page:

```
<a href="page1.html#section1">Page 1</a>
<a href="page2.html#section2">Page 2</a>
```

Second Page:

```
<div id='section1'></div>
<div id='section2'></div>
```

---

edit after comment:

You can use `window.location.hash` like:

```
window.location.hash = "jump_to_this_location";
```

Example:

```js
window.location.hash = "jump_to_this_location";
```

```html
<div style="height: 4000px">uygyuguyguyguyguyg</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<span id='jump_to_this_location'>Jump here!</span>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div style="height: 4000px">tyfytfytfytfytfytf</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I tried using anchor tags but to no avail. It still only links to the topmost section of the page and not the one which I want to. I think the JavaScript functions are overriding this.

Comment: i add another solution